# How To Set A Default Value in an AMPscript subject line?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We are adding personalization to our subject lines in SFMC. This is currently the code we use to pull their first name into the subject line:

```
%%[ set @billingFirstName = ProperCase([billingFirstName]) ]%% %%=v(@billingFirstName)=%%
```

How can I set a default value if there isn't a billingFirstName in our data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend adding this AMPscript in the body of your email (or better in an init code-resource template slot) and then referring to the variable in the subject line:

```
%%[

set @billingFirstName = AttributeValue("billingFirstName") 
set @subject = "Welcome to the Club!" /* default subject */

/* personlize SL if billing name exists */
if not empty(@billingFirstName) then
  set @subject = concat("Welcome to the Club, ", properCase(@billingFirstName), "!")
endif

]%%
```

Subject:

```
%%=v(@subject)=%%
```